# Logstash Rabbitmq connection refused

Tags: elasticsearch, rabbitmq, logstash, kibana-6

Have installed Elasticsearch-6.6.0 and kibana-6.6.0 in Windows core 2016 Server it is up and running, I had to index the data from Rabbitmq, so downloaded and unzipped logstash-6.0.0 and made a config file for rabbitmq as follows

```
input {
    rabbitmq {
        arguments => { "x-ha-policy" => "all" }
        host => "172.xx.xx.xx"
        queue => "xx.flow.queue"
        #durable => true
        key => "flowtrack"
        exchange => "xx.test.exchange"
        threads => 120
        exclusive => false
        prefetch_count => 512
        vhost => "/"
        port => 5672
        user => "usr"
        password => "Pass@123"
    }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["172.xx.xx.xx:9200"]
  }
}
```

Ran logstash through commandline as follows

```
    c:\logstash-6.0.0>bin\logstash -f config\rabbitmq.conf
```

but it throws error as follows

```
 [2019-02-20T23:01:28,696][ERROR][logstash.inputs.rabbitmq ] RabbitMQ connection error, will retry. {:error_message=>"Connection to localhost:5672 refused", :exception=>"MarchHare::ConnectionRefused"}
    [2019-02-20T23:01:28,696][ERROR][logstash.inputs.rabbitmq ] RabbitMQ connection error, will retry. {:error_message=>"Connection to localhost:5672 refused", :exception=>"MarchHare::ConnectionRefused"}
```

Port 5672 is open in host
Let me know if i have missed anything in configuration which is leading to this error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found the issue, it was due to route not enabled in server. Now connection between Logstash and Rabbitmq is established and indexing is done.